# Send Tab Name to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I have an ActionBar with tabs and a ViewPager to swipe through the tabs. I need to send the name of the tab to the fragment that is being created (in my case there is only 1 fragment created for every tab). The name of the tab (ie. tab.getText()) changes the content within the fragment so I need to have the name of the fragment. I try to put it in my onTabSelected but it doesn't work when I send it a static string

```
public static String tabName;    
....

public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            tabName = tab.getText();

}
```

When I call MainActivity.tabName in my fragment it does give the tabText() but it is slow, meaning when I switch tabs it doesn't get the tabText right away and then it ends up thinking tab 1 is tab 3 or tab 3 is tab 2, etc.

Comment: I answered this yesterday here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25642099/grab-tabtext-in-fragment/25646416#25646416

Comment: If all you want is to have tabs by clicking on which(or by swiping left or right)respective fragment is shown then refer [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/).

Comment: @Sash_KP possibly a school assignment.